# Compatibility issue with HTC Explorer / Desire C (320 x 480 Screen Resolution)

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-compatibility

I have uploaded my application to Google Play Store with the following Permissions and screen support in the Android Manifest.

When I checked in the Compatible Device list, its not showing up Devices like HTC Explorer with a screen resolution of 320 x 480 px.  Please suggest me what changes I need to make in the Manifest.XML file to make the compatibility

```
     <compatible-screens>
    <!-- small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />  
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />   
    <!-- large screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>



 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>  
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Answer (score 0):

set this tag in Manifest file, set true of false based on your application to support

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

anyDensity = support all resolutions

largeScreens = 7” tablet(600x1024)

normalScreens = Normal screens(480x800)

smallScrens = Small screens(320x480,240x360)

XlargeScreens = 10” tablet(720x1280, 800x1280, etc)

Comment: I am using <compatible-screens> Tag already, so why again the Support Screens Tag?

Comment: read the Caution: statement in the following link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html, and follow the link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html by according to googleplay filters